how do i prevent a keyboard event from repeating if its key is being held down in actionscript?
im making a little flash game in as3 and i want the character to "boost" fowards when jumping mid air, but the jumping variable me and my friend made updates even if the up arrow is held down
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
level.gotoAndStop(1);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);

var speedX = 0;
var speedY = 10;
var keys = [];
var jumping = true;
player.gotoAndStop(1);

function gameLoop(event:Event):void {
    speedX = 0;
    
    if (player.x > 550) {
        level.nextFrame();
        player.x = 0
    }
    if (player.x < 0) {
        level.prevFrame();
        player.x = 500
    }
    
    for(var i:Number = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        
        switch(keys[i]) {
            case 38: // Up arrow key
                if(jumping){
                    player.gotoAndStop(3);
                    speedX = 10 * player.scaleX;
                    break;
                } 
                speedY = -16;
                jumping = true;
                break;
            
            case 37: // Left arrow key
                speedX -= 5;
                player.scaleX = -1;
                player.gotoAndStop(2);
                   break;
            
            case 39: // Right arrow key
                speedX += 5;
                player.scaleX = 1;
                player.gotoAndStop(2);
                break;
        }
    }
    if(speedX == 0) player.gotoAndStop(1);
    player.x += speedX;
    player.y += speedY;
    speedY++;
    while(level.hitTestPoint(player.x, player.y + player.height / 2, true)) {
        player.y--; // Place player above the floor
        speedY = 0; // Reset vertical speed
        jumping = false;
    }
    while(level.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width / 2, player.y, true)) {
        player.x--; // Place player above the floor
        speedX = 0; // Reset vertical speed
    }
    while(level.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width / 2, player.y, true)) {
        player.x++; // Place player above the floor
        speedX = 0; // Reset vertical speed
    }
}

function keyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(keys.indexOf(event.keyCode) == -1) keys.push(event.keyCode);
}

function keyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    var index:Number = keys.indexOf(event.keyCode);
    if(index != -1) keys.splice(index, 1);
}

everything works as expected, but how do i prevent the jumping variable from updating while the key is held down? i want a foward boost while jumping mid-air (sorry if im wording stuff incorrectly, its my first post here)

You do not check released keys at all, and your mechanics looks like it requires a trigger to happen when the key for jumping has been released, in order to prepare your game logic to react on a "double jump" properly. I say you reprogram your gameLoop "for keys" cycle to directly check all the keys (it'll then also be better to store keys in a static array instead, so you can say query keys[KEY_JUMP] for jumping processing logic, while also allowing you to stop hardcoding keys), and act on the key's state; say if the key for jump is pressed, and the character is standing on ground, you initiate "first jump", if released mid-jump, you change player state for "jump ended" and process subsequent presses as required for your game logic.
And there is another mistake in your code - you try to reposition your player to be "above the floor" each frame, even if there's still no floor to be hit and the player travels upwards; you only need to check for collisions "down" if the player's speedY is 0 or higher (that is, the player is moving down); otherwise your collision detection is triggered on the very first frame the player jumps up and resets its position and speed right away. It should likely read:
if (speedY > 0) while(level.hitTestPoint(player.x, player.y + player.height / 2, true)) {
    player.y--; // Place player above the floor
    speedY = 0; // Reset vertical speed
    jumping = false;
}

The same speed control should be used for X-side collisions; if you're moving left, you should not control if your right side collides with a wall.
Also you should probably have another variable that depends on whether your player is in mid-air, which is separate from your "jumping", this will also simplify your game logic for coding.

oh, sorry excuse me mate, but ive already fixed the problem, i should have closed the question
